# HoC component connected to redux arround component connected to redux

Tags: reactjs, inheritance, redux, higher-order-components

I have base component, let's say `BaseContainer` that connects to redux and has some methods. Now I want to create few `CustomContainer` components that should be connected to redux too and should have access to all methods and state of `BaseContainer` component.

So `BaseContainer` would be:

```
class BaseContainer extends React.Component {
   state = {};
   
   method1() {};
   method2() {};
   method3() {};
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BaseContainer);
```

And one of `CustomContainers` should be:

```
   class CustomContainer extends BaseContainer {
       // should have access to all imports, methods and props of BaseContainer
    }
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CustomContainer);
```

Tried this but seems that inheritance does not work well in React and it is not recommended too.
Here I get error `Super expression must either be null or a function`.

Tried other approach with using HoC:

```
class CustomContainer extends React.Component {
           // should have access to all imports, methods and props of BaseContainer
        }
        export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BaseContainer(CustomContainer));
```

and now I'm facing error: `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Object(...) is not a function`

What is wrong and how can I achieve that my `CustomContainer` has access to all imports, props and state of `BaseContainer` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably read over the react docs, specifically [Composition vs. Inheritance](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html). React favors composition over inheritance. `BaseContainer` also isn't a Higher Order Component, but rather it's a regular component, and it doesn't appear to return anything to render.

[Higher Order Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)

Here's an implementation I think would help get you close to what you're after

```
const withBaseCode = WrappedComponent => {
  class BaseContainer extends Component {
    state = {};

    method1 = () => {...}
    method2 = () => {...}
    method3 = () => {...}

    render() {
      return (
        <WrappedComponent
          method1={this.method1}
          method2={this.method2}
          method3={this.method3}
          {...this.props}
        />
      );
    }
  }

  const mapStateToProps = state => ({...});
  const mapDispatchToProps = {...};

  return connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BaseContainer);
};
```

Then to use it's just a normal HOC, so given some component

```
const CustomContainer = ({ method1, method2, method3, ...props}) => {
  ...

  return (
    ...
  );
};

const CustomContainerWithBaseCode = withBaseCode(CustomContainer);
```

Some App container

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      ...

      <CustomContainerWithBaseCode />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Demo of above code minus *actually* connecting to a redux store.

[image: Edit Higher Order Component Example]